# Can Codeigniter's core functions work from within custom functions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I have many controllers that use the same blocks of code that take varying sets of arguments. These blocks of code are identical, which I would like to move into a Helper File, which I can then call, instead, as a function in my controllers.

However, when I move the code into a custom Helper, core functions of CI just don't work.

For example, I've autoloaded my Database and Session classes and call them frequently in my controllers. I have a block of code (that I use many, many times throughout my application) that takes some session data, runs it against a database query, and then returns values.

When I replace that code with a custom function (I've placed the code in its function in my custom helper file), pass arguments, and try to run the code, the application halts whenever I try to run a database query with the arguments, pull in session data, or even try to echo any uri segment.

I know I have the helper file placed and configured properly, because I am able to call custom functions that do not use any of Codeigniter's libraries.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the trick is $CI =& get_instance();  check this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: why you didn't accept right answer? it's comes up your reputation

Answer (score 0):

Per the codeigniter docs:

Once you've assigned the object to a variable, you'll use that variable instead of $this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, helpers are not supposed to work that way:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/helpers.html

> Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in
>   an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each
>   helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on
>   other functions.

You will not be able to use information from your session and database directly inside helpers, unless you pass individual properties as parameters to the helpers.

If you want to use common code that uses other aspects of Codeigniter such as sessions and database, you should create a new Codeigniter **Library**, not a CI Helper.

Answer (score 0):

in helper you don't have access to codeigniter functionality so first of all get instance of codeigniter

`$CI =& get_instance();`

after that load anything you want with $CI for example `$CI->load->helper('url');` insted of `$this->load->helper('url');`